# trying to make navigation bar background color r:1 g:68 r:148

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

tried this

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 1/255, green: 68/255, blue: 148/255, alpha: 1)
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes =[NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.white]
```

and also tried this

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 68, blue: 148, alpha: 1)
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 68, blue: 148, alpha: 1)
UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 68, blue: 148, alpha: 1)
```

Can anyone help me achieve correct color. I must be using the various params wrong

thanks

Comment: `1 / 255` is an integer division, which results in 0. Try `1.0 / 255.0`

Comment: From where you are applying these values? And do you want to change it globally or for any particular screen?

Answer (score 0):

Your code will always return 0 .

Change

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 1/255, green: 68/255, blue: 148/255, alpha: 1)
```

to

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 1.0/255.0f, green: 68.0/255.0f, blue: 148.0/255.0f, alpha: 1.0)
```

Comment: is not int it is float

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Didn't got you. Please elaborate a bit

Comment: Because colors are 8bit values hence range lies b/w 0 to 255 hence divide by 255, so it returns float

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Yes, I know that thing. But 1/255.0 will also return float value as well as 1.0/255.0 . Please correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 1.0/255.0, green: 68.0/255.0, blue: 148.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

Give Float values